# What is wrong with how I initialized a double pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

When I run my program just hangs. Is there anything wrong with the my double pointer setup? If I comment this out my program doesnt hang.

```
double **transverse;
transverse = malloc(rows*sizeof(double*));  //allocate memory to double pointer
for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    transverse[i] = malloc(rows*sizeof(double*));
    for (j = 0; j < rows; j++)
        transverse[i][j] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second allocation is wrong

```
transverse[i] = malloc(rows*sizeof(double*));
```

It should be

```
transverse[i] = (double*)malloc(rows*sizeof(double));
```

`traverse[i]` is a `double *`, therefore, you need to use `sizeof(double)`.

Comment: Ah thanx. Dont know how I missed that.

Answer (score 3):

```
for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    //Just double for allocating memory for double pointer transverse[i]
    transverse[i] = malloc(rows*sizeof(double));  //<-- remove double*
    for (j = 0; j < rows; j++)
        transverse[i][j] = 0;
}
```